# Get data from row where column values are using interchangeably

Tags: sql, sql-server

The data I'm getting in the image is correct(Link is below).Please look at the below query.

```
SELECT * FROM dbo.DrugInteraction WHERE Drug='clarithromycin' AND DrugInteraction='afatinib'
SELECT * FROM dbo.DrugInteraction WHERE Drug='afatinib' AND DrugInteraction='clarithromycin'
```

If look closely then you can see that ,Column values for Drug and Druginteraction is use interchangeably and I have thousands of records like this,but the description remains same.

So, the final input I want is that the description field only.Can anybody help me in this.

[image: Current Data]

Comment: Please tag your question with the database you are using.  I also find the question ambiguous.  What if drug appears appear multiple times in your table?  What if the interaction descriptions are not the same?

Comment: I am using SQL SERVER database

Comment: May be it appears twice but with different drug interaction and the description remains same.

Answer (score 0):

You can get the "first" value for each pair using:

```
select di.*
from dbo.DrugInteraction di
where drug < druginteraction
union all
select di.*
from dbo.DrugInteraction di
where drug > druginteraction and
      not exists (select 1
                  from dbo.DrugInteraction di2
                  where di2.drug = di.druginteraction and di2.druginteraction = di.drug
                 );
```

Comment: Hi Gordon,It works.Can you please suggest me how we can do this in linq,it would be very helpful?

Comment: @sunil . . . I don't use linq.  This question is tagged "sql" only.  I would suggest that you ask another question, include this query and a reference to this question, and tag it "linq".